# Cypress getByTestId, queryByTestId, findByTestId to check if element doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, cypress, end-to-end

I am trying to check if element doesn't exist in a DOM Tree with Cypress and testing-library/cypress.

If I try to do `cy.getByTestId("my-button").should("not.exist")` test fails because it couldn't find element.

If I do `cy.findByTestId("my-button").should("not.exist")` it also fails because of time out.

The test does work if I do either `cy.queryByTestId("my-button").should("not.exist")` or

`cy.get('[data-testid="my-button"]').should("not.exist")`.

Can someone please explain what's the difference between all 4.

Thanks

Comment: Some of those aren't part of the Cypress API - are you also using e.g. https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro?

Comment: Yes, I am using "testing-library/cypress"

Comment: Might be worth raising an issue with the maintainers if they behave differently from the built-in methods.

Comment: See this [comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/testing-library__cypress/index.d.ts#L34), says **findBy*` APIs search for an element and throw an error if nothing found**, so logically you cannot use `cy.findByTestId(...)` with `.should("not.exist")`

Comment: Thanks, I found the same information in here https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet, saying that `findBy` and `getBy` return error if element isn't found that's why cannot be used for my test. `queryBy` returns null and doesn't fail the test. But what does `cy.get('[data-testid="my-button"]')` return when element is not in a DOM?

Answer (score 12):

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries

- `getBy` will throw errors if it can't find the element
- `findBy` will return and reject a Promise if it doesn't find an element
- `queryBy` will return null if no element is found:

> This is useful for asserting an element that is not present.

looks like `queryBy` is your best choice for this problem

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Cypress Testing Library they have removed `queryBy`.

[Cypress Testing Library | Intro](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/)

If you want to check if something doesn't exist just use findBy, but put a should() straight afterwards. It won't time out in that case.

```
cy.findByText('My error message').should('not.exist')
```

[Discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library/issues/30#issuecomment-452949967)

Comment: As of end of 2023 this should be the accepted answer